# Using BCrypt.Net to simulate Devise Password Encryption?

Tags: c#, mysql, ruby-on-rails, devise, bcrypt

I am trying to a pretty simple task here. I have a server that I am running which has a MySQL instance running on it, which my rails app uses to populate. Unfortunately for me I used devise to do all my user management and now am a little stuck.

So I have a C# application that I am writing. I want to simply verify the user and password through the MySQL database that I have already in place.

Right now here is what I know (or think I know):

Devise uses Bycrypt to do a one way encryption on their passwords which are then stored in the database. The problem is that I am not sure how to implement bycrypt properly to produce the proper encrypted passwords to validate.

Here is my current process for generating my hashed password:

```
string pass = password.Text;
string mySalt = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt();
string myHash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(pass, mySalt);
```

I think that this must be really wrong. I just don't quite know what I am missing here or what I am doing wrong. I will keep googling around and if I come up with an answer I will post back. Also if I broke any editting rules or something just let me know so I can fix them right quick.

Thanks in advance for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so my question was actually pretty silly but for anyone else with the same logical fallacy as me I'll explain.

By default Devise does it's encryption using BCrypt, which is typically done with Blowfish, when they do this they always use BCrypts generate salt function which produces a random salt for each hashing of the password.

Because of the random salt BCrypt includes a utility function called Verify(password, hashed_pass). This function allows the testing of a non encrypted password and hashed pass to be compared. Nifty and very useful

Comment: Were you able to verify the password based on the devise way? Can you please share code?

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is your generating the Salt each time you are hashing the password to verify against the database. You need to use the same Salt value that was used when the password was initially generated.

Comment: You are indeed correct! I believe that is a feature of the Devise encryption for passwords. I am looking into it at the moment but I believe there is a verify equal function that tests for equality given the current hash. I will post more after testing